# Unrecognized token 'using' when trying to add new row to a Smartsheet

Tags: c#, json, smartsheet-api

**Hello,**

**I'm new to REST and JSON but i'm trying to setup a C# code to add new rows to a SmartSheet via API. I've tested this in POSTMAN and gotten the response listed below, anyone know what i'm missing? The token has been used to perform a Get on the same Smartsheet without issue **

```
using Smartsheet.Api; 
using Smartsheet.Api.Models; 
using Smartsheet.Api.OAuth;

    // Set the Access Token. Token token = new Token(); token.AccessToken
    = "22cskc65swmgihz7znr58xbe9w";

    // Use the Smartsheet Builder to create an instance of SmartsheetClient. SmartsheetClient smartsheet = new SmartsheetBuilder().SetAccessToken(token.AccessToken).Build();

    // Get current user. smartsheet.UserResources.GetCurrentUser();

    // Get server info. smartsheet.ServerInfoResources.GetServerInfo();


    Cell[] cellsA = new Cell[] { new Cell.AddCellBuilder(5499304161896324, true).Build(), new Cell.AddCellBuilder

    (7751103975581572, "New status").SetStrict(false).Build() };


    Row rowA = new Row.AddRowBuilder(true, null, null, null, null).SetCells(cellsA).Build();


    Cell[] cellsB = new Cell[] { new Cell.AddCellBuilder(5499304161896324, true).Build(), new Cell.AddCellBuilder

    (7751103975581572, "New status").SetStrict(false).Build() };


    Row rowB = new Row.AddRowBuilder(true, null, null, null, null).SetCells(cellsB).Build();


    smartsheet.SheetResources.RowResources.AddRows(sheetId, new Row[] { rowA, rowB });
```

**Using POSTMAN i'm getting the following error returned**

```
{
  "errorCode": 1008,
  "message": "Unable to parse request. The following error occurred: Unrecognized token 'using': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: REST input; line: 1, column: 7]",
  "refId": "13ve7m9i2m942"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Please revoke the access token that you pasted and create a new one as people can use that to access your account.**

You are receiving the stated error because you are pasting C# code into POSTMAN which POSTMAN cannot handle. You will need to use [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) if you want to run C# code.

If you would like to use POSTMAN you can only send one request at a time to a specific URL. For example, if you want to get information about your current user you would tell POSTMAN to go the https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/users/me endpoint (step 1 below) using your token (step 2 below) then click "Send". Here is a screenshot of what that will look like:

[image]